# ruby passing the value of a hash to a method

Tags: ruby, methods, hash

I'm new to ruby but I'm experimenting with it using watir-webdriver. I'm trying to work out how I can pass a hash value to a method like so:

```
#this is a hash in ruby - a collection of keys and values
title = { :Mr => "Mr", :Mrs => "Mrs", :Miss => "Miss", :Ms => "Ms", :Other = > "Other"}

def select_title(title)
 @browser.element(:xpath => "//input[@type='radio'][@value='Value of title hash']").click
end
```

I don't want to write an if then else or switch like logic inside the method, just pass the value of the hash straight into the xpath? how?

Comment: What do you mean using wording “value of the hash”?

Comment: I'm saying I want the hash key to be passed to the method and the value of the key to be passed to the xpath - does that make sense? sorry totally new to ruby might have used incorrect terminology...

Comment: Have you tried the `send` function in Ruby? Im not entirely sure if this will help you, but here's the docs for it http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-send basically it send the specified argument to a specified method. So what you could do is methodize the `xpath` and send the hash value to the `xpath` method

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, here you go:

```
def select_title(title_hash_key)
  @browser.element(:xpath => "//...[@value='#{title[title_hash_key]}']")
          .click
end
```

Now when the hash key is passed to this method as an argument, the respective value will be fetched from the hash and put into `xpath` string using string interpolation (`#{title[title_hash_key]}`.)

Comment: I think what I actually need is something like an enum so when I call the method I'd be doing something like select_title(title.Mr)

Comment: This will work if you’ll pass the key, e.g. `:Mr` to it. The value `"Mr"` will be looked up against the hash and placed into `xpath` string.

Comment: I'm possibly making this to complicated... I guess I could just send the string directly to the method